# How do you make your own agar.io skins?

Tags: agar.io

I have noticed recently that people have their own skins. Not like the ones where you type in a specific nickname and it gives you a skin but where the people make their own. How do you do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can request a skin by submitting it [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Agario/comments/34r8n0/post_your_skins_here_and_the_dev_might_add_them/).

Be sure to follow all the instructions & requirements!

---

Also some agario extensions like 'agariomods.com' allow you to submit your own skins too, you have a bigger chance for it to get added there. The problem with it is that only others with that extension installed (the agariomod) can see it.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what @Actually Unnamed said, you can create a skin using the "skin creator" option (introduced in 2019). Here's how to create a skin in the mobile version of Agar.io:

1. Click the **create** button:

   > [image: step 1]
2. Write/draw whatever you want. You can change the background colour and the border colour as well:

   > [image: step 2]
3. Rename your cell and press **save** (here it shows 'free' because Agario gave me a free skin as a reward for something I don't remember now):

   > [image: step 3]

The method of creating skins is virtually the same as that on PC. (Also note that you can upload "images" through the skin creator but for that, you will have to install [Agartool](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/386800/274520) (an extension).)

Answer (score -3):

You really can't do this unless you have a mod, [like this one.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/agariomods-evergreen-scri/nhjgdbihpkphlammdaeicdemggagfbdo?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog)

If you still want a skin use this:

## Chrome, IE and Firefox

[Download](https://agariomods.com/index.html)

[Links](http://connect.agariomods.com/index.php)

## Chrome

## Firefox