# Can I play with a friend on the same IP as me?

Tags: agar.io

Let's say that I am at a friend's house. Is it possible to play agar.io together, on the same IP?

Comment: Wait.. What was a gaming question doing on [so]?

Comment: if one of the answers below solves your problem above, please mark it as an answer by clicking the tick underneath the downvote arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>It is possible, but slightly complicated:</s>

1. Refresh the page and stay in lobby.
2. Choose FFA or TEAM
3. Press F12 (for google chrome)
4. Click on "Console"
5. Find "Connecting to ws://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx" (x's are ip)
6. Give that IP to your friend, who does the same, except he takes this IP and writes to the console: `connect("ws://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx")` (replace x's with numbers)
7. Check if you're on the same server by matching Leaderboard player names.
8. If you're not, both write `connect` to the console. (it happens sometimes)

They've implemented a mechanism which allows to connect to the same server by sharing a URL. Check it out on the page: enter your name, click on the game mode, select Party, on the right side click "create" and copy & send the URL to your friends.

Enjoy!

Comment: " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined "

This happens :(

Comment: Hmm, it seems that they changed the program, and that broke this method. I'll edit my answer when I find a working solution. You can just keep refreshing the page until you and your friend get on the same server.

Answer (score 0):

What *redbeam_* said only works for *Party Mode*. You can play every game mode with your friends, if you want. In order to do that, you'll need to install an extension that assigns every server (in every game mode!) a specific IP address which you can then share with your friends to play together.

The simplest extension, in my experience, is *"Agartool"*. It has many other features, such as chatting with friends, rapid mass ejection (by pressing and holding <kbd>W</kbd>), unlimited zoom, a map of the lobby and more. There's an IP address right below the play button, which you can copy and send to your friends.

---

To get Agartool for Chrome, follow these steps:

1. Install *"Tampermonkey"* for your respective web browser ([Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo), [Opera](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/tampermonkey-beta/), [Safari](https://tampermonkey.net/?browser=safari), [Mozilla Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tampermonkey/) or [Microsoft Edge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/tampermonkey/9nblggh5162s)).
2. Go to [agartool.io](https://www.agartool.io/) and press "Install". The window will automatically close.
3. Open Agar.io and it's done.

Comment: One final note: I havn't played agar.io in a long time; but it *looks* like your recommending that users install a third-party tool that allows you to exploit or have an unfair advantage over other players. *This may not be received well*. If I am mistaken, it might help to include a note clarifying why this tool would be considered 'legal', just in case other readers make the same mistake.